# Error connecting to Onedrive with Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, sharepoint, onedrive

I am attempting to read the XLSX file in Sharepoint that is fed from an Excel Form. I am utilizing python 3.x to write the script for this.

I am attempting to create a solution to capture user comments for some of our processes - which are currently handled via shared excel files on network drives, and is a very messy outcome. I have found a number of articles on SO and other sources that indicate I need to authenticate with Sharepoint and am trying to get this to work in the code below.

I am importing the following libraries ->

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import 
AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.file import File
```

And I have another section that is bringing in my credentials from an encrypted file. I have checked the variables those are populating (username, password) and verified that those are correct.

```
ctx_auth = AuthenticationContext(url)
if ctx_auth.acquire_token_for_user(username, password):
    ctx = ClientContext(url, ctx_auth)
    web = ctx.web
    ctx.load(web)
    ctx.execute_query()
    print("Authentication successful")

response = File.open_binary(ctx, url)
#save data to BytesIO stream
bytes_file_obj = io.BytesIO()
bytes_file_obj.write(response.content)
bytes_file_obj.seek(0) #set file object to start

#read excel file and each sheet into pandas dataframe 
df = pd.read_excel(bytes_file_obj, sheetname = 'Form1')
```

I am expecting the connection to work and populate my DF from the sheet in excel -  but am getting the following error message - which made me initially think my credentials were not coming through properly, but they are.
I am also the owner of the folder that I am trying to access, so there are no permissions issues with my credentials access that folder.

```
An error occurred while retrieving token: AADSTS90023: Invalid STS 
request.
An error occurred while retrieving auth cookies
------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
--
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-7-90f58cf903a0> in <module>
     32     web = ctx.web
     33     ctx.load(web)
---> 34     ctx.execute_query()
     35     print("Authentication successful")
     36 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\office365\runtime\client_runtime_context.py in 
execute_query(self)
     36 
     37     def execute_query(self):
---> 38         self.pending_request.execute_query()
     39 
     40     def add_query(self, query, result_object=None):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\office365\runtime\client_request.py in execute_query(self, query, 
result_object)
     25         if query:
     26             return self.execute_single_query(query, 
result_object)
---> 27         return self.execute_pending_queries()
     28 
     29     def execute_pending_queries(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\office365\runtime\client_request.py in 
execute_pending_queries(self)
     31             for query in self.__queries:
     32                 request = self.build_request(query)
---> 33                 response = self.execute_request_direct(request)
     34                 self.process_payload_json(query, response)
     35         finally:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\office365\runtime\client_request.py in 
execute_request_direct(self, request_options)
    102     def execute_request_direct(self, request_options):
    103         """Execute client request"""
--> 104         self.context.authenticate_request(request_options)
    105         if request_options.method == HttpMethod.Post:
    106             from office365.sharepoint.client_context import 
ClientContext

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\office365\runtime\client_runtime_context.py in 
authenticate_request(self, request)
     14 
     15     def authenticate_request(self, request):
---> 16         self.__auth_context.authenticate_request(request)
     17 
     18     @property

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\office365\runtime\auth\authentication_context.py in 
authenticate_request(self, request_options)
     33         """Authenticate request"""
     34         if isinstance(self.provider, SamlTokenProvider):
---> 35             request_options.set_header('Cookie', 
self.provider.get_authentication_cookie())
     36         elif isinstance(self.provider, ACSTokenProvider) or 
isinstance(self.provider, OAuthTokenProvider):
     37             request_options.set_header('Authorization', 
self.provider.get_authorization_header())

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\office365\runtime\auth\saml_token_provider.py in 
get_authentication_cookie(self)
     67 
     68         logger.debug_secrets("self.FedAuth: %s\nself.rtFa: %s", 
self.FedAuth, self.rtFa)
---> 69         return 'FedAuth=' + self.FedAuth + '; rtFa=' + self.rtFa
     70 
     71     def get_last_error(self):

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```